# Create new Character variables from Date variable in sas

Tags: variables, sas, character

I have the following data set:

```
Date

May2005
May2005
May2005
June2005
.
.
.
May2006
May2006
May2006
.
.
.
May2007
May2007
May2007
```

I am trying to create three new variables such that Date05 = May2005 when Date1 = May2005, Date06 = May2006 when Date1 = May2006, and so on.

I thought of the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
data new;
set afinaldelaware;
if (Date1 EQ '01May2005'd or Date1 EQ '01May2006'd or Date1 EQ '01May2007'd)     
then do;

Date05 = '01May2005';
Date06 = "01May2006';
Date07 = 'May2007';
end;
run;
```

Comment: What is Date05, a variable not shown or your reference to the fifth value of the Date variable?

Comment: Is Date1 numeric with a date format or character containing 'mmyyyy' string? with 'ddmmmyyyy'd you are resolving as numeric. Also you are fullfilling date05 date06 date07 if date1 is in that list. Is this correct?

Comment: Date1 is mmyyy7. format. I want to create the three new variables: 
Date05, Date06 and Date07.

Answer (score 0):

Since your dates are formatted as `mmyyy7.` you don't know the exact date which is likely why your comparison fails. You can compare the month and year using the respective functions instead of date literals. Note that you're creating character variables not SAS date variables, which may be what you intend.

```
data new;
set afinaldelaware;
if (month(date1)=5 and year(date1) in (2005 2006 2007))     
then do;

Date05 = '01May2005';
Date06 = "01May2006';
Date07 = 'May2007';
end;
run;
```